# JQuery: How to hide a div with a dynanically assigned ID

Tags: jquery, json

I have a $.getJSON call that's too long to post here.  It all works fine except when I try to hide a div.  My data is coming back from the database in the callback as "data" and is processed in a "for" loop (with "i" as the increment) in the callback.  All of my data displays elsewhere fine.  But when I try to do this:

```
var div = '#row' + data[i].id;
$(div).hide();
```

it fails.

I can replace "data[i].id" with the row number from the database and the div is hidden.  If I alert div, I get "#row664" or whatever.  Something about the combination of "#row" and the dynamically generated ID is causing the hide to fail.

The HTML in the same callback is:

```
   html = '<div id="row' + data[i].id + '">';
```

The HTML is appended to a div at the end of the callback.  Everything else works, like I said.  So it seems like this should work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you appending a brand new div, then trying to hide it?

Comment: yes.  This works fine when I am using the hardcoded row number but not with the json.

Comment: Rather I appending the HTML and I am hiding some of it.

Comment: If you look at the Javascript console (e.g. by using Firebug in Firefox), does it give an indication that $(div) isn't available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you append the div before you hide it.

```
var div = '#row' + data[i].id;
var html = '<div id="' +div+ '">';
$('body').append(html);
$(div).hide();
```